# Reset environment variable with batch file

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I would like reset all environment variable except those in a list.

I try this :

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set notToChange=APPDATA PATH
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('set') do (
    for /f "delims==" %%j in ("%%i") do (
        set "var=%%j"
    )
    if "%notToChange%"=="%notToChange:!var!=%" (
        set !var!=
    )
)
```

I have a problem with :

```
if "%notToChange%"=="%notToChange:!var!=%"
```

it does not work. I do not understand why.

Comment: Even if it can be done, it seems to be a bad idea

Comment: Indeed.  Seems like a reboot would be safer.  :)

Comment: It is very useful when you want test a soft and verify that you have all librairies in your package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion doesn't work the way you hoped.
You need to use another FOR-Loop to be able to replace the variable.
The additional loop copies the variable `var` to the parameter `%%V`

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "notToChange=APPDATA PATH notToChange"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('set') do (
    for /f "delims==" %%j in ("%%i") do (
        set "var=%%j"
    )

    for /F "delims=" %%V in ("!var!") do (
          if "!notToChange:%%~V=!" == "!notToChange!" (
              set "!var!="
          )
    )
)
```

After reading the solution of Magoo, I realized the problem of the `notToChange` variable, so I added some code to avoid that problem

Btw. This will delete the variables only inside the batch file, as after the end the `setlocal` will be implicitly reverted by an `endlocal`, restoring all variables

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "notToChange=APPDATA PATH"
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('set') do IF /i "%%i" neq "nottochange" IF /i "%nottochange%" equ "!nottochange:%%i=!" ECHO clear %%i

GOTO :EOF
```

I'd advise extreme caution with this routine. I've simply commented that the variable is to be cleared (`set "%%i="` should clear it if that's what you truly want to do...)

Not that `nottochange` needs to be in the don't-change-me list.

Comment: The problem of the `notToChange` variable itself is an important point.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
set "notToChange=APPDATA PATH"
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set') do (
    set "remove=1"
    for %%b in (%notToChange%) do if /i "%%a"=="%%b" set "remove="
    if defined remove set "%%a=" & set "remove="
)
set
```

Seeing the already posted code I don't know if I'm missing something, but this should do the work.

**edited** Yes, what i was not seeing is that it is not as easy as i was thinking. It is easier

```dos
(
    for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set') do  set "%%a="
    set "PATH=%path%"
    set "APPDATA=%appdata%"
)
set
```

**edited** again. This will also work if you want to keep using the configuration variable

```dos
set "notToChange=APPDATA PATH"

for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set') do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if not defined notToChange set "notToChange=%notToChange%"
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!notToChange:%%a=!=") do (
        endlocal 
        if /i "%notToChange%=" equ "%%b" set "%%a="
    )
)
set
```